# Correct Xpath for Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am a soccer fan, trying to learn scrapy. However, I am running into some xpath related problems and was wondering if someone could help please. I am on https://whoscored.com/Statistics page and trying to get all the information on the 2774 players. This might sound like a total newbie question but how do I scrape the names of the players? I tried using

```
`response.xpath('//*[(@id = "player-table-statistics-body")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "player-link", " " ))]/text()').extract()`
```

but it doesn't scrape anything. I got the xpath by using selectorgadget in Chrome. However,

```
`response.xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), 
concat( " ", "player-link", " " ))]/text()').extract()`
```

works but it scrapes all the names in the Statistical XI list also which I don't want. Would really appreciate some help here. Thanks!

@Steve this is what I am doing in the scrapy shell:

```
scrapy shell https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics
response.xpath('//*[(@id = "player-table-statistics-body")]//*[contains(@class, "player-link")]/text()').extract()
```

I would think that this will give me the ten names that I am looking for, but it doesn't. I am really clueless at this point!

Comment: @alecxe Sorry, my bad. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

The xpath `('//*[(@id = "player-table-statistics-body")]//*[contains(@class, "player-link")]/text()')` gets 10 players from the "Player Statistics" table.

What were you trying to achieve with the concats?

Comment: Steve, thanks for the reply. Well, like I mentioned, I just copied the xpath that the selectorgadget plugin in Chrome gave out which contained the concat() function. My knowledge on xpaths is next to none and I am in the process of figuring that out for starters. However, I tried your xpath as follows : `response.xpath('//*[(@id = "player-table-statistics-body")]//*[contains(@class, "player-link")]/text()').extract()` but that too didn't give me the result I was hoping for. There must be something fundamentally wrong that I am doing here.

Comment: I use Firebug with Firefox and it's been pretty reliable. The other handy debug tool is the [scrapy shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#scrapy-shell). Add your code to your question and we'll have another look.

Comment: Looks like that part of the page is dynamically generated by javascript, which makes sense. You will need to use something like Selenium to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Xpath will work for you.

```
player_list = respose.xpath('//*[@id="overall-formation-seasonal-content"]//li//a[contains(@class,"player-link")]/text()')
```

Comment: Usman, Not quite. The xpath that you are referring to is for the Statistical Best XI at the bottom of the page which is not dynamically being generated. I am looking for the "player-table-statistics-body" which as @Steve rightly pointed out, I will have to use Selenium.